# Unity2D - Blend tree not acknowledging position parameters in animations

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

Context:

I have a prefab fox character. It is a gameobject with an animator, the child of that is its body with all the other necessary stuff, and the children of the body are all the body parts.

Each body part has its own layer in the animator. All parts are Override. Apply root motion is ON, write defaults is OFF for all the blend trees and ON for everything else

This fox character (which is basically a prefab for randomly generated characters) has a NavmeshAgent component.

Problem:

All works accordingly, except that when the fox's navmeshagent takes sharp turns or turns at all or diaganol movements, the body parts slide around.

You will note the muzzle does not do this despite it also being on a blend tree. I think this is partly due to the fact its position never changes, it only has one position for all directions, and disappears on all but one.

Transition Duration is 0, exit times are off on all transitions and animation states.

Things tried:

setting root motion on/off for the animator

switching different layers to Additive/Override (best to just keep them all on Override)

Tweaking variosu other settings

What I've Discovered:

Interestingly, ONLY the blend trees have an issue, aside from the aforementioned muzzle. For example, when I set the fox to a sleeping/sitting state, the body parts align perfectly, and it traverses through the map on its navmeshagent without ANY sliding from the body parts.

However, when it comes to the walking blend trees for all the body parts, it slips and slides and creeps out of place whenever turning.

I've done a lot to debug, but I just cannot find the issue/solution.

EXAMPLE: https://files.fm/u/8hbjdttyq2

The video shows everything mentioned above.

I'm stumped, and I would really appreciate any help you can throw my way so the body parts stop sliding.

Blend tree of one of the parts: